# jq display key names and their child element lengths together

Tags: arrays, json, key, jq

I would like to display an arbitrary object's key names and the lengths of their constituent parts.  I think that my trouble appears to be with 'length' requiring a filter, which mutes other output.

Given foo.json contains:

```
{
    "lol": 1, 
    "wtf": [1, 2, 3, 4], 
    "bbq": {
        "omg": "yes", 
        "afk": "always"
    }
}
```

I can:

```
cat foo.json |jq 'keys'
[
  "bbq",
  "lol",
  "wtf"
]
```

And I can:

```
cat foo.json |jq '.[] |length'
1
4
2
```

But how do I get both on the same (or I would even accept alternating) line?

```
"bbq" 2
"lol" 1
"wtf" 4
```

Comment: I'm confused; this filter `'.[] |length'` produces an error.

Comment: Why would you want the length of .wtf (4) on the same line as "lol"?  Do you really want the jq `length` of scalar values here?

Comment: @peak you are 100% correct - that is not what I wanted, and you identified it - question edited.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Assuming you want each key with its length on the same line, you could go with something like:

```
jq -r 'keys_unsorted[] as $k | [$k, (.[$k]|length)] | join(" ")'
```

If you want the key name to be quoted, use the filter:

```
keys_unsorted[] as $k | "\"\($k)\" \(.[$k]|length)"
```

Comment: Thank you very much @peak - why doesn't just regular `keys[]` work here? Why must we specify `keys_unsorted[]`?

Comment: If you want the key names to be sorted, use `keys`.  Is that not clear from the jq manual?

Comment: I swear I tried this with `keys` and it didn't work - I just ran it again to check and now it is.  I don't know what I was doing wrong the first time; please disregard.